# Does Octave support enumeration like Matlab?

Tags: matlab, octave, enumeration

Does Octave support **enumeration** like Matlab?
I haven't found any info about it.

We can create an enumeration class by adding an enumeration block to a class definition. For example, the WeekDays class enumerates a set of days of the week (from Matlab doc).

```
%file WeekDays.m
classdef WeekDays
   enumeration
      Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday
   end
end
```

And it work well in Matlab and I access enum values as

```
x = WeekDays.Tuesday;
```

but **Octave** doesn't compile this line, despite file WeekDays.m is compiled by Octave without errors.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Wiki says it is not supported: http://wiki.octave.org/Classdef

Comment: Yes. Not supported. Thanks. Maybe we should contribute and implement it :p

Comment: I know this is not what you're asking, since your question seems to focus on the "new OOP style" (i.e. classdef) syntax, but it's worth noting that it is trivial to create enum functionality using the "old OOP" style, which is technically still octave's preferred OOP syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that in Octave version 4.0 there is experimental support for `classdef`-based object-oriented code, including `enumeration` blocks.

**Edit:** looks like I was wrong, and enumerations are not yet supported, as indicated in the comment below from @carandraug (who I believe is an Octave developer, so probably knows better then me).

Comment: not true. Octave's experimental implementation of classdef in version 4.0 does not support enumeration yet. Maybe in the next release.

Comment: @carandraug In the third bullet point of [this newsletter](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/NEWS-4.0.html) it seems to say that the experimental support includes the keywords `enumeration` and `endenumeration`. Is that misleading? For example, are they now keywords in v4.0, but they're only placeholder keywords in order to provide future support for enumerations?

Comment: Kind of. The parser does recognizes enumeration and won't error  when used as in `enumeration\nMonday (0)\nTuesday (1)\n...` but then there is no way to actually access those values yet.

Answer (score 0):

The code example above still doesn't compile, in Octave 5.1.0 on a Mac. It gives the error:

octave:1>    enumeration
warning: the 'enumeration' function is not yet implemented in Octave

Progress on enumeration is tracked here:
https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?44582

Answer (score 0):

You can use static functions as a partial workaround:

```
classdef WeekDays
    methods (Static = true)
        function [out] = Monday()
            out = "Monday";
        end

        function [out] = Tuesday()
            out = "Tuesday";
        end

        function [out] = Wednesday()
            out = "Wednesday";
        end

        function [out] = Thursday()
            out = "Thursday";
        end

        function [out] = Friday()
            out = "Friday";
        end
    end
end
```

Similarly, you can also create enumerated objects; I've uploaded template to google drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-HftS5pdzE-oTmaC0kbnYcAcyAsaEcX6

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of completeness, here's an octave-style OOP 'enumerator' example:

```
% @Weekdays/Weekdays.m
function Obj = Weekdays( Weekday )
  Obj.enumeration = {'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'};
  if nargin == 0;   error( "Weekday cannot be initialized empty; choose from 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', or 'Sunday'."); end
  if ~ismember( Weekday, Obj.enumeration );   error( sprintf( "%s is not a valid Weekday. Choose from 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', or 'Sunday'.", Weekday ) ); end
  Obj.value = Weekday;
  Obj = class( Obj, 'Weekdays' );
end
```

```
% @Weekdays/display.m
function display(Obj);   display( get( Obj ) );   end
```

```
% @Weekdays/get.m
function Out = get( Obj );   Out = struct(Obj).value;   end
```

```
% @Weekdays/set.m
function Obj = set( Obj );
  error( "Enum objects have no public properties that can be set");
end
```

---

<sub>PS. if you really *must* have dot-syntax access, I suppose you can overload subsref accordingly too.</sub>